# Printing a single tibble row over multiple lines of text

Tags: r, tibble, drake-r-package

It is sometimes desirable to print a string in a `tibble` over multiple lines. Example: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/489. [`drake` plans](https://ropensci.github.io/drake/reference/drake_plan.html) with long commands are hard to read.

```
library(drake)
pkgconfig::set_config("drake::strings_in_dots" = "literals")
drake_plan(
  u_auckland = make_place(
    Name = "University of Auckland",
    Latitude = -36.8521369,
    Longitude = 174.7688785
  ),
  shapefile = {
    file_out("u-auckland.prj", "u-auckland.shx", "u-auckland.dbf")
    st_write(
      obj = u_auckland,
      dsn = file_out("u-auckland.shp"),
      driver = "ESRI Shapefile",
      delete_dsn = TRUE
    )
  }
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   target     command                                                      
#> * <chr>      <chr>                                                        
#> 1 u_auckland "make_place(Name = \"University of Auckland\", Latitude = -3…
#> 2 shapefile  "{\n    file_out(\"u-auckland.prj\", \"u-auckland.shx\", \"u…
```

Can [`pillar::pillar_shaft()`](https://pillar.r-lib.org/) or a similar tool to achieve something nicer? I am mainly concerned with line breaks and indentation (possibly with [`styler`](https://github.com/r-lib/styler)) but I am also interested in syntax highlighting, possibly with [`hightlight`](https://github.com/romainfrancois/highlight) and [`crayon`](https://github.com/r-lib/crayon).

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  target     command                                             
* <chr>      <drake_cmd>
1 u_auckland make_place(
               Name = "University of Auckland",
               Latitude = -36.8521369,
               Longitude = 174.7688785
             )
2 shapefile  {
               file_out(
                 "u-auckland.prj",
                 "u-auckland.shx",
                 "u-auckland.dbf"
               )
               st_write(
                 obj = u_auckland,
                 dsn = file_out("u-auckland.shp"),
                 driver = "ESRI Shapefile",
                 delete_dsn = TRUE
               )
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently this is [currently not possible as such](https://github.com/r-lib/pillar/issues/125), but a [great workaround](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/489#issuecomment-410072186) was suggested for my original use case.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/700 and https://github.com/ropensci/drake/pull/708.